# Get a Single Object nested in array MongoDB

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, object, cursor

I've been trying to query out a single object with find or findOne from a MongoDB Database array of Objects.

Im trying to pull a "clientteams" nested object using it's teamid.

$user['team'] is a string of 59dcf4d1fd82f416ac00608d belonging to the heroes team.

Document Example

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5a018682a8102a27349741cc"),
   "clientteams":[  
      {  
         "teamid":ObjectId("59dcf4d1fd82f416ac00608d"),
         "name":"heroes"
      },
      {  
         "teamid":ObjectId("59dde7effd82f42c6000062a",
         "name":"villions"
      }
   ]
}
```

PHP code i've tried always returns the full document.

```
$team = $collection->findOne(['clientteams.teamid' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( $user['team'] )],[ 'clientteams' => [ '$elemMatch' => [ 'teamid' => $user['team'] ]]]);

$team = $collection->findOne(['clientteams.teamid' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( $user['team'] )], ['clientteams.$' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation type, you need to use the **aggregate**, i did do a test and it worked, this is a query:

```
    YOUR_COLLECTION.aggregate([
        { $unwind: "$clientteams" },
        { $match: { "clientteams.teamid": ObjectId("59dcf4d1fd82f416ac00608d")} }    
    ]);
```

Now, if your need filter the result, you can use **$project** after **$match**